# How to extract parent elements of a specified button using its xpath?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to access a `button` element's source url (that it takes you to once its clicked).

However, looking into the html, the button's nested inside a few classes of the main parent `<a>` element. Im trying to find a way to access that via `get_attribute` however its not working

At the moment its `returning None` for the *cta_url* because of course the *parent_element* is not the main parent. Below is the code block in question

```
for i in range(20):
            starting_element.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
            tab_wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//body/div/div/div[@role='main']/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]")))
            starting_element = browser.switch_to.active_element
            time.sleep(1)
            # check for a set of keywords when a CTA button is targeted, if matched then extract URL from source
            if starting_element.aria_role == 'button':
                button_text = starting_element.text
                if button_text in meta_cta_buttons:
                    parent_element = starting_element.find_element(By.XPATH, "..")
                    cta_url = parent_element.get_attribute('href')
                    print(cta_url)
            else:
                continue
```

The page im referring to is [this](https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=active&ad_type=all&country=ALL&q=%22%20%22&start_date%5Bmin%5D=2023-02-07&start_date%5Bmax%5D=&search_type=keyword_exact_phrase&media_type=all&content_languages%5B0%5D=en).
[This is the button im talking about for full context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIHDF.png)

Edited additional info -> HTML element in question below.

```html
<a class="x1hl2dhg x1lku1pv x8t9es0 x1fvot60 xxio538 xjnfcd9 xq9mrsl x1yc453h x1h4wwuj x1fcty0u x1lliihq" target="_blank" href="https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fsalankaracreation.com%2Fproducts%2Fsalankara-creation-designer-drop-fitted-naksha-bala%3Futm_content%3DFacebook_UA%26utm_source%3Dfacebook%26variant%3D42342785024177%26fbclid%3DIwAR2lR9RPGQqnisFtySxqLr6BZgNmLU-TdRsT-SOF2h4syzfIAoY28E8SX5M&amp;h=AT3CWaIDaXpKVTEKF3uYuZ56OpneGn978po8Fmdt1K4Dzfb6w_iVhgSiF1tuBAoze9JSfPDOhbiDQa5zbgUVLGj75QM6o4HQhgtqPazAFRo7mRFx43-qk0J84U2Xxf78QTw" rel="nofollow noopener" data-lynx-mode="hover" data-lynx-uri="https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fsalankaracreation.com%2Fproducts%2Fsalankara-creation-designer-drop-fitted-naksha-bala%3Futm_content%3DFacebook_UA%26utm_source%3Dfacebook%26variant%3D42342785024177%26fbclid%3DIwAR0F44dXcdztlWq0w3l55eFaO6lkc8T-abjcok_Z4YRosIEFo7nVRvHP1zI&amp;h=AT3CWaIDaXpKVTEKF3uYuZ56OpneGn978po8Fmdt1K4Dzfb6w_iVhgSiF1tuBAoze9JSfPDOhbiDQa5zbgUVLGj75QM6o4HQhgtqPazAFRo7mRFx43-qk0J84U2Xxf78QTw" style="" xpath="1"><div class="x1ywc1zp x78zum5 xl56j7k x1e56ztr x1277o0a"><img alt="" class="x1ll5gia x19kjcj4 xh8yej3" referrerpolicy="origin-when-cross-origin" src="https://scontent-ord5-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t39.35426-6/329103301_714332536939836_1381434036214193350_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s600x600&amp;_nc_cat=109&amp;ccb=1-7&amp;_nc_sid=cf96c8&amp;_nc_ohc=UhFGxKsW874AX9Xc-Ej&amp;_nc_ht=scontent-ord5-1.xx&amp;oh=00_AfAW7WlYCfzcgAaYzDOUzkJtPa1u8nYcwC9ARHVfbWmKJQ&amp;oe=63ECBC09"></div><div class="_8jgz _8jg_"><div class="x1iyjqo2 xw3qccf x6ikm8r x10wlt62 xt0b8zv"><div class="_8jh5"><div tabindex="0" role="button"><div class="_4ik4 _4ik5" style="line-height: 12px; max-height: 24px; -webkit-line-clamp: 2;">SALANKARACREATION.COM</div></div></div><div class="_8jh2"><div tabindex="0" role="button"><div class="_4ik4 _4ik5" style="line-height: 14px; max-height: 28px; -webkit-line-clamp: 2;">Salankara Creation Designer Drop Fitted Naksha Bala</div></div></div><div class="_8jh3"><div tabindex="0" role="button"><div class="_4ik4 _4ik5" style="line-height: 14px; max-height: 28px; -webkit-line-clamp: 2;">₹1,449</div></div></div><div class="_8jh4"><div tabindex="0" role="button"><div class="_4ik4 _4ik5" style="line-height: 12px; max-height: 24px; -webkit-line-clamp: 2;"></div></div></div></div><div class="_8jh0"><div class="x3nfvp2 x193iq5w xxymvpz" role="none" style="max-width: 120px;"><div aria-busy="false" class="x1i10hfl xjqpnuy xa49m3k xqeqjp1 x2hbi6w x972fbf xcfux6l x1qhh985 xm0m39n x9f619 x1ypdohk xe8uvvx xdj266r x11i5rnm xat24cr x1mh8g0r x2lwn1j xeuugli x16tdsg8 xggy1nq x1ja2u2z x1t137rt x6s0dn4 x1ejq31n xd10rxx x1sy0etr x17r0tee xdl72j9 x1q0g3np x193iq5w x1n2onr6 x1hl2dhg x87ps6o xxymvpz xlh3980 xvmahel x1lku1pv xhk9q7s x1otrzb0 x1i1ezom x1o6z2jb xo1l8bm x108nfp6 xas4zb2 x1y1aw1k xwib8y2 x1swvt13 x1pi30zi x78zum5 x1iyjqo2 xs83m0k" role="button" tabindex="0" style=""><span class="x8t9es0 x1fvot60 xxio538 x1heor9g xq9mrsl x1h4wwuj x1pd3egz xeuugli xh8yej3"><div class="x78zum5"><div class="xeuugli x2lwn1j x6s0dn4 x78zum5 x1q0g3np x1iyjqo2 xozqiw3 x19lwn94 x1hc1fzr x13dflua x6o7n8i xxziih7 x12w9bfk xl56j7k xh8yej3"><div class="x8t9es0 x1fvot60 xxio538 x1heor9g xuxw1ft x6ikm8r x10wlt62 xlyipyv x1h4wwuj x1pd3egz xeuugli">Shop Now</div></div></div></span></div></div></div></div></a>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do. What is the purpose of the loop whose index is `i`? What do you mean by "the _main_ parent"? Can I suggest you update your question to include a code block that contains the relevant fragment of HTML, and a clearer description of what it is that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: NB when I read "parent elements of a specified button", I want to point out that any given element (such as a button) can have only 1 parent. Are you referring to the set of elements consisting of the element's parent, its grandparent, its great-grandparent, etc? If so, these are properly called its "ancestor" elements.

Comment: @ConalTuohy thanks for the response. Yes that is the case, apologies I didn't know what they were called. I have updated the question with the relevant HTML code, with the ancestor element I need to extract the URL from. And to clarify, im just testing right now the `tab-keyboard` button to maneuver through the page, as such `i` is just the element its on at the moment. Im sure theirs a better way to do it, but thats outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Can you put the HTML into a code block please? Not an image.

Comment: @ConalTuohy wasn't sure how to  do it cleanly at first, but take a look now.

Comment: What is `meta_cta_buttons`? I still don't see what it is that you're trying to do. I _think_ you are trying to find an `href` hyperlink attached to ancestor `a` element of the currently selected element, so long as the currently selected element has an aria role of 'button' and has text which is one of a set of strings (something to do with "cta").

Comment: `meta_cta_buttons` was just a list for all relevant call to action buttons for ads on the page that meta provides. The goal was to traverse the page, using the tab-key, and stop once a button is selected, then extract the url from the appropriate ancestor element. Not to worry though I figured it out. see solution if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to my own problem, for finding the ancestor elements; after starting from a specific initial element (in this case a button).

All I did was add a while loop to look keep traversing backwards in the element heirarchy, until an element with `tag_name` being `a`. Since that parent would have the `href` url for the button I want to extract.

Below is the edited code block which solved my issue now.

```
for i in range(20):
        starting_element.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
        tab_wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//body/div/div/div[@role='main']/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]")))
        starting_element = browser.switch_to.active_element
        time.sleep(1)
        # check for a set of keywords when a CTA button is targeted, if matched then extract URL from source
        if starting_element.aria_role == 'button':
            button_text = starting_element.text
            if button_text in meta_cta_buttons:
                parent_element = starting_element.find_element(By.XPATH, "..")
                while (True):
                    if parent_element.tag_name != 'a':
                        #moves up element ancestry chain 
                        parent_element = parent_element.find_element(By.XPATH, "..") 
                    else:
                        cta_url = parent_element.get_attribute('href')
                        print(cta_url)
                        break
        else:
            continue
```